# Mount external HDD readOnly option

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, ssd, mount

I have the following problem: I used the optical bay to use a HDD in my mid 2010 13" Macbook Pro in addition to my SSD. It was working just fine until a few days ago, when it started to get "slower". VLC Player (on SSD) wasn't able to play videos on the HDD anymore, and when I tried to copy files from the HDD to the SSD it took ages (the speed was about 20 mb/m). Also it took a really long time to see what's in a folder when I opened it (but after 5-10 seconds I could at least see what files were in which folder).

My first question is: Is my HDD slowly dying? What could the problem be?

A friend was trying to help me repair it (he tried several things in the terminal and in safe mode - I do not remember all of it, but anyhow.. nothing worked). During this we unmounted the HDD and since then I am not able to mount it anymore.
When I try

```
diskutil mount /dev/disk1s2
```

in the terminal it says

```
Volume on disk1s2 failed to mount If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

How can I try to mount it in readOnly mode?

```
diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk1s2
```

doesn't work..

I would really appreciate it if you could help me. I have a lot of new photos and music on the HDD I have not backed up yet.

Comment: Additional info: I removed the HDD from the Macbook and put it into an external case.
And the HDD seems to be ok from the outside. At least it doesn't make any unusual sounds like other dying HDDs.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Enter in Terminal.app:

```
sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk1s2 --settype "Apple_HFS"
```

and then try:

```
diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk1s2
```

Comment: hey look at this: 

$ sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk4s1 --settype "Apple_HFS"
Trace/BPT trap: 5    
$ diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk4s1    
Volume on disk4s1 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option

Comment: this still didn't work for me: I got the same error

Comment: when entering `diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk1s2` the same output occurs: `If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option`

Comment: The solution was straightforward: `sudo pkill -f fsck`

Running your command without understanding what it does was a bad decision and has made things worse for me. I now need to format my hard disk.

It happened to me before also and I was able to fix this by just running the command that I shared earlier.

Answer (score -1):

TO your first question, yes probably your disk is dying :(

To your second question, try mounting with either `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk1s2` or `diskutil mountDisk readOnly /dev/disk1s2`

This is required if there are multiple partitions in the disk, read man page of diskUtil, that would help.

Comment: How does mounting a volume as a disk (if this even works) solve the issue described in the question?